# read from a datagridview to a list and add to another datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi I'm trying to read from a datagridview to a list. In this each row in the datagridview is added as an object to the list. I'm reading all the data from the first datagridview to an object list and then I'm going to display all of those records in the second datagridview by clicking a button. Here's my code and it's giving me the error Object reference is not set to an instance of an object. 
Can anyone correct this?
Here's my code..

```
 List<ClsOBJ> list1 = new List<ClsOBJ>();
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                ClsOBJ userobj = new ClsOBJ();
                     userobj.username=dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                userobj.userid=dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                list1.Add(userobj);




            }

            BindingSource binding = new BindingSource();
            binding.DataSource = list1;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = binding;
            MessageBox.Show("Added");
        }
        catch(Exception xx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(xx.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the exception showing up? What object does it reference?

Comment: @AlexBarac

Here's what I'm getting
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Mine.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Mine is the name of the program

Comment: Have you put break points in your code to find out which object is null?

Comment: @FodderZone

How to do that?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Answer (score 0):

First: which line is giving you the exception?

Second: get rid of the 'try-catch' for a moment and when the exception is thrown, put a cursor over each of the names of the properties in the problematic statement. Find out which value is 'null'

Third: 
On the first glance it is the fault of this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

If **Value** of the cell is null, then calling **ToString()** on it will throw an exception.

Also, does your DataGridView has an **AllowUserToAddRows** set to **true** (by the way, it's the default)? If that's the case, then 
**dataGridView1.Row[dataGridView1.NewRowIndex]** has nulls in it.

You can check if the row is not a NewRow:

```
if(!dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].IsNewRow)
{
    // do something...
};
```

Comment: The exception throwing code line is 

userobj1.username = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
I set AllowUserToAddRows to false and used the if condition too. No it has a new problem. No exception thrown, but when I click the add button NOT all the records in the first datagridview is added but the 1st record and the third record. Then in the second click the second row is added and in the third click fourth record is added. Now what is the problem??

Comment: The exception throwing code line is userobj1.username = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString(); I set AllowUserToAddRows to false and used the if condition too. No it has a new problem. No exception thrown, but when I click the add button NOT all the records in the first datagridview is added but the 1st record and the third record. Then in the second click the second row is added and in the third click fourth record is added. Now what is the problem??

Comment: @ddg what items are actually in the list1 after the foreach()? I don't mean what is shown in dataGridView2, but the actual content of list1. Also check if none of this happens: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror(v=vs.90).aspx